# How can I configure Netbeans to save AppData to anoter location?

Tags: netbeans

Dear Netbeans developer.

For my Webapplications I use Oracle´s IDE Netbeans 7.3 on Windows 7. My Problem: Netbeans saves a lot of data in my user Profile´s AppData-Folder: `C:\Users\simon\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans`. There are nearly 800 MB and my system administrator is not very happy about that.

How can I configure Netbeans to save that data to anoter location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the NetBeans "userdir". Details in the [NetBeans FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir)

Specifying a different userdir is also documented in the FAQ: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir